# WPF/C# Assigning a ViewModel to a custom control from parent view

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm very new to C# and WPF, and I'm struggling a bit to get data where I need it.

I have one master set of data, which needs to be shared with various user controls, each of which have their own ViewModel. The problem is that I don't seem to be able to assign a ViewModel to a control from the parent XAML and then access that ViewModel from within the custom control's XAML.

I bind the control to a Viewmodel, but then the datacontext within the control doesn't allow me to access that model within the xaml, or I can set the datacontext in the user control so I can access its viewmodel, but then I can't bind to the viewmodel in xaml (because the binding is looking in the local datacontext, not the parent).

I may be going about this all wrong, most examples I've seen seem to instantiate a ViewModel in the custom control xaml, but then I don't see how you get that ViewModel to reference the correct DataModel (or specific part of the datamodel).

The following hopefully explains what I am trying to do.

Firstly I have my data model, in DataModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BindingTest1
{

    public class DataModel
    {
        private List<string>[] _dataLists;
        public List<string>[] DataLists
        {
            get { return _dataLists; }
        }


        public DataModel()
        {

            List<string> list0 = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
            List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };
            _dataLists = new List<String>[] { list0, list1 };
        }
    }
}
```

In MainViewModel.cs

```
namespace BindingTest1
{
    class MainViewModel
    {
        private MyViewModel _myFirstViewModel;
        public MyViewModel MyFirstViewModel
        {
            get { return _myFirstViewModel; }
        }

        private MyViewModel _mySecondViewModel;
        public MyViewModel MySecondModel
        {
            get { return _mySecondViewModel; }
        }

        private DataModel _dataModel;
        public DataModel DataModel
        {
            get { return _dataModel; }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _dataModel = new DataModel();
            _myFirstViewModel = new MyViewModel(_dataModel.DataLists[0]);
            _mySecondViewModel = new MyViewModel(_dataModel.DataLists[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <!-- These were just to check the data was being set up properly -->    
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel.DataLists[0]}"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel.DataLists[1]}"/>

        <!-- this is what I want to be able to do -->
        <local:MyView ViewModel="{Binding MyFirstViewModel}"/>
        <local:MyView ViewModel="{Binding MySecondViewModel}"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(Codebehind is default)

In MyViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BindingTest1
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        private List<string> _dataList;
        public List<string> DataList
        {
            get { return _dataList; }
        }

        public MyViewModel(List<string> list)
        {
            _dataList = new List<String>(list);
            _dataList.Add("Some Local Processing");
        }
    }
}
```

MyView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingTest1.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.DataList}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Codebehind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BindingTest1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyView : UserControl
    {
        public MyViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (MyViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(MyViewModel), typeof(MyView), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnViewModelChanged)));

        public MyView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void OnViewModelChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Just making sure the right thing is being received
            List<string> dataList = (e.NewValue as MyViewModel).DataList;
            foreach(string line in dataList)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: normally you don't need specialized view model for each usercontrol. custom usercontrol should work if you assign some constant values in xaml.   bidnings are expected to take values from DataContext. but if you are going that way, take a look here [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972319/wpf-usercontrol-doesnt-inherit-parent-datacontext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a dependency property here.

Try this.

```
<local:MyView DataContext="{Binding MyFirstViewModel}"/>
<local:MyView DataContext="{Binding MySecondViewModel}"/>
```

and bind the DataList to ItemsSource in the MyView XAML.

As you assigned MyFirstViewModel to the DataContext of MyView, bindings inside will look in MyFirstViewModel for the ItemsSource.

Comment: THANK YOU!! It seems so obvious now I see it, but I've been going round in circles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you ought to do this. Your view doesn't need a ViewModel property. It should bind to properties of its DataContext, which will be the viewmodel.

view:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
```

Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
        <local:MyView 
            />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <!-- ... -->

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyFirstViewModel}"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MySecondViewModel}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting used to WPF and it hadn't clicked with me that DataContext is just one more thing I can bind.