# Create WPF subview with own viewModel for each item in ItemsControl (MVVM pattern)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**Update: I learned that i not mean a "control" but that a "sub view" is what i mean. I updated the question so it uses the correct term/word**

I'm a beginner in WPF and MVVM and run into the following issue.

I have a `JobsView` with it's own `JobsViewModel` view model. The `JobsView` contains a `ItemsControl` which should show my `JobWidget` for each job in `Jobs` (a list which exists in the `JobsViewModel`).

So far it works fine, it shows a `JobWidget` for each `Job` in the list. I'm even able to bind some `Job` parameters to the `JobWidget` like the Job's `Name` or `Status`.

The `JobsView`

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ECRO.MVVM.View.JobsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:widget="clr-namespace:ECRO.MVVM.Widgets"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" Height="780">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:JobsViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Jobs" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}"/>
        <ScrollViewer Width="780" Height="700">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Jobs}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:JobWidgetViewModel}">
                        <widget:JobWidget/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The `JobWidget`

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ECRO.MVVM.Widgets.JobWidget"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="90" d:DesignWidth="760">
    
    <!--<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:JobWidgetViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>-->

    <Grid>
        <Grid Height="90" Width="760">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="677*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="123*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border CornerRadius="10"
                    Background="#353340"
                    Height="80"
                    Margin="10,0,10,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                        <!--<RowDefinition Height="50*"/>-->
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                    Margin="5 2 0 0">
                        <Label Content="Naam" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="Status" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="Laatste run" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="Volgende run" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Status}"  Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding LastRun}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding NextRun}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                    </StackPanel>


                    <Border Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Margin="0 0 20 0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Content="Forceer run" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Width="100"
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.ForceRunJobOnceCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Content="Start" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.StartJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Content="Stop" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.StopJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Content="Disable"
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.DisableJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Content="Bewerk" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.EditJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As my `JobWidget` contains some buttons (and later it wil get some "view logic" and will be reused on other places in the application) i want that it has its own `ViewModel` which "receives"/contains the `Job` object from the parent (the `ItemsControl` in `JobsView`). Here my issue starts.

I'm not able to "bind?" a view model to the `JobWidget` so it has the concerning `Job` object. I tried to add the snippet bellow to my `JobWidget` but that only breaks the binding that displays the `Name` and `Status`.

```xml
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:JobWidgetViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

I also tried things like this in the `ItemsControl` of `JobsView`:
`<widget:JobWidget DataContext="{Binding control:JobControlViewModel}"/>`
and
`<widget:JobWidget="{Binding}"/>` (and other versions/variations on both)

I found related questions on stackoverflow (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980662/wpf-c-assigning-a-viewmodel-to-a-custom-control-from-parent-view) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972319/wpf-usercontrol-doesnt-inherit-parent-datacontext)) but i was not able to get it working so i would appreciate some help.

What i noticed is that the `JobControl` seems to use the `JobsViewModel` which is the view model of it's parent (`JobsView`). This is not what i want as i need to duplicate code on each place i want to use the `JobWidget`.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you wrong or you me. The `JobsView` is not the custom control but the view that contains the custom control. -- You say a control must not have its own private view model. Where should i write the controls logic in that case? I mean write the control logic in its parent does not make sense to me as it results in code duplication each time i re-use the control. -- Maybe i use the wrong term and is my "custom control" more a child view which should have its own `ViewModel` ?

Comment: A control like your JobControl should not have its own view model. It should expose bindable properties (i.e. dependency properties in WPF). One of those properties *could* be of type JobControlViewModel, so that you could bind it like `<control:JobControl JobControlData="{Binding}"/>` in the ItemTemplate in JobsView.

Comment: The terminology does not make a difference. You still have a UserControl that should expose dependency properties. Where exactly is your problem with that idea?

Comment: And of course the "control's logic" would be implemented in its code behind, typically in a set of PropertyChangedCallback methods of its dependency properties. You may have heard of the idea that MVVM means that there must not be any code behind in a view. This is a misconception, and while generally wrong, it is especially complete nonsense when it comes to custom control code.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your reactions but they rais new questions. - Should a `<UserControl>` never have a view model? (I have a `Window` with a `ContentControl` which shows "pages", they are `UserControl` with VM's) - What logic should be in te view model and what in the code behind? (thought only view logic like change colors/button states etc. should be in code behind, data related stuff like caling functions on objects in the view model?)

Comment: In my opinion only those elements should create their own view model that are at the top of a visual tree. These are Windows, Pages, or maybe "top-level" UserControls that are the root Content of a Window or Page. All other elements should operate on view model instances that they access by the inherited value of their DataContext property.

Comment: For your JobWidgetit is essential that it does not set its own DataContext, otherwise it would not work with standard data binding, e.g. in an ItemTemplate. When you decide to implement a certain functionality of a complex control in separate classes, that would be an implementation detail and not qualify as a view model in the sense of the pattern.